# unable to change the scope of my settings in .net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, settings

can anyone tell me how to change the scope from application to user in .net.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You set the asp.net-mvc tag so I assume you are creating a web application.

The scope of settings is actually useful in client application. The application scope settings are stored in the application directory, where the user scope settings are stored in the user profile (in order to allow a non-admin user to change them). As it is in the user profile, each users can have a separate settings file.
All of this is handled by the configuration framework.

In web apps, it's completely different. The configuration framework, whichever user is logged in, will use the config in web.config file.
If you want to have per-user settings, you will have to manage them yourself.
There are OOB classes to manage the profiles : [`ASP.NET Profile Properties Overview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx) which is good place to start.